# NivoSlider jquery issue

Tags: jquery

I have nivoslider jquery used in my project. In that banner should slide in random manner (Now it is sliding in a serial wise)

Please find the code for your reference:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(window).load(function () {
            jQuery('#slider').nivoSlider({
                pauseTime: 5000,
                effect: 'fold', //Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
                slices: 1
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({ theme: 'light_rounded' });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
jQuery('#slider').nivoSlider({
    pauseTime: 5000,
    effect: 'random', 
    slices: 1
});
```

Comment: He doesn't want a random effect.  He wants random order ;)

Comment: @Archer Ah ok, I understood differently.